# undefined error when I want to display photographer card using DOM

Tags: javascript

I get an undefined error when I'm trying to extract my JSON into a DOM

The photographerList is showing up in the console but in my webpage I get an undefined error

example result in index.html with undefined:

[image]

console log of the dom working with undefined below

[image]

I really don't understand why this thing is not working

Here's the photographer.js code :

```
function photographerFactory(data) {
  const { name, city, country, tagline, price, portrait, id } = data;

  const picture = `assets/photographers/${portrait}`;
  const photographersSectionHTML = document.querySelector(
    ".photographer_section"
  );

  function getUserCardDOM() {
    let photographerList = "";
    photographerList += `<article>
    <a href="./photographers.html">
    <img src="${picture}"> </img>
    <h2 alt="${name}">${name}</h2> 
    </a>
    <h3>${city}</h3>
    <p> ${tagline}</p>
    <p>${price} </p>
    </article>`;
    console.log(photographerList);
  }
  return {getUserCardDOM };
}
```

here's the index.js code

```
async function getPhotographers() {
  
  let url = './../data/photographers.json';
    try {
      let res = await fetch(url);
      return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

async function displayData(photographers) {
  const photographersSection = document.querySelector(".photographer_section");
  photographers.forEach((photographer) => {
    const photographerModel = photographerFactory(photographer);
    const userCardDOM = photographerModel.getUserCardDOM();
    photographersSection.innerHTML = userCardDOM;
  });
}

async function init() {
  // Récupère les datas des photographes
  const { photographers } = await getPhotographers();
  displayData(photographers);
}

init();
```

```js
// photographer.js
function photographerFactory(data) {
  const {
    name,
    city,
    country,
    tagline,
    price,
    portrait,
    id
  } = data;

  const picture = `assets/photographers/${portrait}`;
  const photographersSectionHTML = document.querySelector(
    ".photographer_section"
  );

  function getUserCardDOM() {
    let photographerList = "";
    photographerList += `<article>
    <a href="./photographers.html">
    <img src="${picture}"> </img>
    <h2 alt="${name}">${name}</h2> 
    </a>
    <h3>${city}</h3>
    <p> ${tagline}</p>
    <p>${price} </p>
    </article>`;
    console.log(photographerList);
  }
  return {
    getUserCardDOM
  };
}

// index.js 

async function getPhotographers() {

  let url = './../data/photographers.json';
  try {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function displayData(photographers) {
  const photographersSection = document.querySelector(".photographer_section");
  photographers.forEach((photographer) => {
    const photographerModel = photographerFactory(photographer);
    const userCardDOM = photographerModel.getUserCardDOM();
    photographersSection.innerHTML = userCardDOM;
  });
  console.log(photographersSection)
}

async function init() {
  // Récupère les datas des photographes
  const {
    photographers
  } = await getPhotographers();
  displayData(photographers);
}

init();
```

```css
@import url("photographer.css");
body {
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90px;
}

h1 {
  color: #901C1C;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
}

article img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

article p {
  margin: 0;
}

article h3 {
  color: #901C1C;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 5px;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.photographer_section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 150px 40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.photographer_section article {
  justify-self: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.photographer_section article h2 {
  color: #D3573C;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.photographer_section article img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="FR-fr">

<head>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Fisheye</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="./index.html">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Fisheye Home Page" class="logo" />
    </a>
    <h1>Nos photographes</h1>
  </header>
  <main id="main">
    <div class="photographer_section"></div>
  </main>
  <script src="./scripts/factories/Photographer.js"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/pages/index.js"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/pages/photographer.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Why so overly complex? Is the task to have as much await and async in your code as possible?

Comment: it is for a class project but the async functions were given at the beginning

Comment: Ok. Because the lot could be done in like 15 lines of code.

Comment: yes maybe but before i really want to understand why that doesn't work like that

Comment: If you click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and return an example object in the  getPhotographers()  instead of a fetch, then we can see what is wrong

Comment: This is not right I feel: `let photographerList = "";
    photographerList += \`<article>` it is not a loop. Use a map plus a join

Comment: i've add snipet but i do not know how to add multiple js

Comment: Like you did, but when I change your `getPhotographers` to just do `return await [{......},{.......}]` I still get undefined in `const {  photographers  } = await getPhotographers();`  - There is a reason I do not like promises.

Comment: i'm still searching but  i really don't get it

Comment: the thing is that when i do a console.log (photographers) in my async function init it returns the good array so what's wrong ?

Comment: Some kind of OOP issue? You call it a factory, but it does not look or behave like a factory

Comment: i've console.log(photographersSection) and it returns me this
        <div class="photographer_section">
        </div>

Comment: mplungian i've found the result ! it's below !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in fact here's the result after some help and research
i've to return the `photographerList` inside of the `GetUserDom()` function
and `photographersSection.innerHTML = userCardDOM;` is wrong and have to be replaced by

```
photographersSection.innerHTML += userCardDOM;
```

Answer (score 1):

While we wait for some promise specialist, here is a much simpler version

```js
const picturePrefix = `https://picsum.photos/id/`,
  photographersSectionHTML = document.querySelector(".photographer_section"),
  url = './../data/photographers.json';

function displayData(photographers) {
  photographersSectionHTML.innerHTML = photographers
    .map(({ name, city, country, tagline, price, portrait, id }) => `<article>
      <a href="./photographers.html">
        <img src="${picturePrefix}${portrait}" />
        <h2 alt="${name}">${name}</h2> 
      </a>
      <h3>${city}</h3>
      <p>${tagline}</p>
      <p>${price}</p>
    </article>`).join("");
}


function getPhotographers() {
  /* fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>  displayData(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))  */

  const data =   [
    { name: "a",  city: "b",  country: "c",  tagline: "d",  price: 1, portrait: "237/200/300", id: 0 },
    { name: "aa", city: "bb", country: "cc", tagline: "dd", price: 2, portrait: "238/200/300", id: 1 }
  ];
  displayData(data);
}

getPhotographers()
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90px;
}

h1 {
  color: #901C1C;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
}

article img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

article p {
  margin: 0;
}

article h3 {
  color: #901C1C;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 5px;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.photographer_section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 150px 40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.photographer_section article {
  justify-self: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.photographer_section article h2 {
  color: #D3573C;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.photographer_section article img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="photographer_section"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the photographerList parameter on

```
const userCardDOM = photographerModel.getUserCardDOM(photographerList);
```

Comment: well i've edited the code in fact it was for test but that doesn't work anyway